# SQLSERVER - is there a way to enforce that only one bit column is true and all others are false, per row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some bit parameters in sqlserver:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TemporalParams](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[fk_id] [int] not null,
[bitparam_1] [bit] NOT NULL,
[bitparam_2] [bit] NOT NULL,
[bitparam_3] [bit] NOT NULL,
...
[bitparam_x] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

How do I enforce only one bit parameter to be true at a time, on a per row basis? My first thought was to define an UPDATE trigger such that when any parameter is updated to 1, the other parameters are set to 0:

This seems inelegant - is there a better way to do this? While only a few params are shown above, there are considerably more than that in actuality.

Comment: With so many mutually exclusive bits, it might be better to have a `Param INT NOT NULL` with the number of the "bit" that you would consider to be set. If you're accessing it with C# then an `enum` would be a perfect match for it as well.

Comment: The column names aren't actually bitparam_x - they're named such that they describe the behavior we want to track the enabling of. That would be a clever solution, though.

Comment: Large numbers of booleans (`bit`) is [a code smell](https://betterprogramming.pub/dont-use-boolean-arguments-use-enums-c7cd7ab1876a) especially when they are mutually exclusive. You should definitely be using a lookup table, check constraint and/or `enum` here

Answer (score 1):

You can use a check constraint.  The simplest method might be:

```
alter table TemporalParams add constraint chk_TemporalParams_bits
    check (1 = (convert(int, bitparam_1) + convert(int, bitparam_1) + . . .)
          );
```

However, if only one is valid at a time, why not just store the name in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TemporalParams](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_id] [int] not null,
    param varchar(255),
    check (param in ('param_1', 'param_2', . . . ))
);
```

Or even better than a `check` constraint here, you can have a reference table with the valid values.

Comment: When you say a reference table, it would essentially be a table that has the [id] of TemporalParams as a foreign key and then the name of the bit column stored in [param]? So a two-column table? I just want to make sure I understand you.

Comment: @HelpfulHound . . . A `parameterId` is a good idea.  But you could also have a one column table if you just wanted to verify the correctness of the values.